# Smoothing Variable Star Data in Python

Tags: python, smoothing

I'm currently working with variable star data and I need to smooth out the time-series data.  I have numerous (tens of thousands) of data points spread out over a range of time.  To make things simpler, I've binned the data into 1001 bins of time, and it is through this averaged data set that I'm attempting to draw a smooth curve through.

I've tried several different methods, but none of them are working perfectly.  The two most promising are performing a convolution with NumPy and using a Savitzky-Golay filter from SciPy.  Some code for this is here:

```
# Define a smoothing algorithm using the convolve function in NumPy.  The function
# will use a window of 3 points surrouding each point.
window_len = 3
kernel = np.ones(window_len, dtype=float) / window_len
y_smooth = np.convolve(full_average_array, kernel, "same")
y_smooth2 = savgol_filter(full_average_array, 11, 2)

# Run the smoothing algorithm for 50 loops to better smooth annoying light curves.
for n in range(0, 50):
    y_smooth = np.convolve(y_smooth, kernel, "same")
    y_smooth2 = savgol_filter(y_smooth2, 5, 3)
```

As I said, neither works perfectly.  Here are some zoomed in pictures of the output:

[image: This shows the waviness of the Savitzky-Golay filter (blue) and the smoothness of the convolution (green), but the Savitzky-Golay filter method better approximates the large dip around phi = 0]

This shows the waviness of the Savitzky-Golay filter (blue) and the smoothness of the convolution (green), but the Savitzky-Golay filter method better approximates the large dip around phi = 0

[image: This shows that the Savitzky-Golay filter method is a much better representation of the minimum than the convolution.]

This shows that the Savitzky-Golay filter method is a much better representation of the minimum than the convolution.

Every time I make increase numbers to make the curve smoother, the curve is a worse approximation to the observed data.  I need a curve that is both quite smooth and a good approximation to the data, but I haven't found a good method to accomplish that.  What functions/methods should I be using in this case?